# Invalid cross-thread access despite using the dispatcher

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have read up about this problem I am having and I cannot seem to find a solution for it. Some people have recommended to use the dispatcher to push the code execution onto the UI Thread. However this does not solve my issue. I am calling this code out of an Asyc method which is before hand called by a Guide object to display a notification. The code which controls the UI stuff is as follows:

```
public bool isDisabled
{
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                });
            enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    color = origionalColor;
                });
            enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and it is being called from

```
    private void nameInputFinished(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int? result = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(ar);

        if (result == 0)
        {
             [...]

             JourneyPanels.getPanel(JourneyPanelTypes.integration).isDisabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Not sure why I am getting the corss-thread exception but I am pretty sure it has something to do with the async method nesting.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Full Exception Stack

```
  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
  at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
  at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, Boolean b)
  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, Boolean b)
  at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.set_IsReadOnly(Boolean value)
  at PocketRitual.Journey.nameInputFinished(IAsyncResult ar)
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.ActionDialogHelper.Complete()
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.ActionDialogHelper.GetMessageBoxResult(Object state)
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your *calling* code you need to run on the main UI thread e.g.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    JourneyPanels.getPanel(JourneyPanelTypes.integration).isDisabled = false;
});
```

There is no need to call `Dispatcher` on your internal property changes because you will be running on the UI thread at that point.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question

Comment: Solved the issue, it was being called by a text box which I did not include in the code above (you probably noticed it by the stack printout)

Comment: Yep, same issue different UI component :)

Answer (score 1):

You've not included the full code, leaving people to guess. I highly doubt isDisabled (BTW, in the .NET world we name properties with capital letters) only has a setter, for instance. I also bet this is used in databinding, and as such the setter has additional code to raise the PropertyChanged event. Best guess is that the PropertyChanged event is being raised on the background thread rather than the UI thread. Design wise it's best to not hide this within the property. It adds unnecessary overhead when you're not in a background thread. When a background thread does anything that will effect the UI, including changing properties that are data bound, that action should be invoked via the dispatcher from the background thread.

Comment: You have a good point, hiding code is not always a good idea and in this case, it was the issue that I decided to excluse a textbox that is being set to read only. However, that said sometimes if I think the issue originates from a certain location I want to simplify the code to others such that people are not reading long lists of code for no reason. Thank you for you'r help.